# don't know how to use tensorflow gradient

Tags: tensorflow

I got a problem when using `tf.gradients` to compute gradient.
my **x** is a `tf.constant()` of a vector **v** of shape `(4, 1)`
and my **y** is the `sigmoid` of **v**, also of shape `(4, 1)`, so the gradient of **y** with respect to **x** should be a diagonal matrix of shape `(4, 4)`.

My code:

```
c = tf.constant(sigmoid(x_0@w_0))
d = tf.constant(x_0@w_0)
Omega = tf.gradients(c, d)
_Omega = sess.run(Omega)
```

the error is

> Fetch argument None has invalid type .

In addition, I think using `tf.gradients` might be wrong, there may be some other functions that can compute this.

My question:

1. point out where I am wrong and how to fix it using tf.gradients
2. or using another function.

Edit:
want to compute the derivative like this: see the vector_by_vector section https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Vector-by-vector
and the result **Omega** would look like the following:

```
[[s1(1-s1)   0         0          0   ]
 [0        s2(1-s2)    0          0   ]
 [0          0      s3(1-s3)      0   ]
 [0          0         0      s4(1-s4)]]
```

where si = sigmoid(x_0i@w_0), where x_0i is the ith row of x_0. 
Generally, compute a vector over another vector, should be a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't calculate gradients for constants. You'll get None op for gradients. That's the reason for your error. One way to calculate gradients would be tf graph (see the code below) Or other way could be using tf.GradientTape in Eager execution mode:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

arr = np.random.rand(4, 1)
ip = tf.Variable(initial_value=arr)
sess = tf.Session()
c_var = tf.math.sigmoid(ip)
Omega = tf.gradients(c_var, ip)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
_Omega = sess.run(Omega)
print(_Omega)
```

Now, you can pass any sized vector. Still, not sure how you will get (4, 4) diagonal matrix for the gradients.